# How can I get the updated date from a bootstrap datetimepicker with the datetimepicker-rails gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, datetimepicker

How can I get the value of the `<input class="date_picker" ...` when the `<div class="bootstrap-datetimepicker-widget" ...` is changed or updated? I need to get the value so I can update other attributes on the same page. Here is my best attempt to react to the 'changeDate' event:

```
$('.datetimepicker').datetimepicker().on('changeDate', function(ev){
    console.log(' date changed '+ ev.date); 
});
```

I'm unable to get any response form this event. I also opened an [issue](https://github.com/zpaulovics/datetimepicker-rails/issues/58) with @zpaulovics's gem but I'm not sure if this is a defect, or if I am not accessing the event correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the plugin's documentation, there is not any event named as `changeDate`. You should have checked out the wrong package or version. To accomplish what you want you may use `dp.change` event.

```
$('.datetimepicker').datetimepicker().on('dp.change', function(ev){
    console.log('date changed: '+ ev.date); 
});
```

See documentation for more details: http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/Events/

See the demo: http://jsfiddle.net/mLwn1t01/ (Click to calendar icon to initiate the calendar)